# Thymeleaf doesn't work with lombok forEach

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, thymeleaf, lombok

I have problem with Thymeleaf "forEach" and Lombok project in spring boot project. 
If I will generate getters and setters, then everything works correctly. In case when I'm using lombok annotations, I'm getting this exception:

> EL1008E: Property or field 'firstName' cannot be found on object of type 'pl.codol.hibernate.model.CustomerEntity' - maybe not public or not valid?

Does anyone have an idea what can be wrong? I read others topics, but they didn't help me to solve my problem.

My POJO class:

```
@Data // I also used @Getter and @Setter, doesn't work
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class CustomerEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CustomerEntity{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {

    private CustomerService customerService;

    @Autowired
    public CustomerController(CustomerService customerService) {
        this.customerService = customerService;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/list")
    public String listCustomers(Model model) {
        List<CustomerEntity> allCustomers = customerService.findAllCustomers();
        model.addAttribute("customers", allCustomers);
        return "list-customers";
    }
}
```

Part of html file which cause problem:

```
<th:block th:each="customer : ${customers}">
<tr>
<td th:text="${customer.firstName}">...</td>
<td th:text="${customer.lastName}">...</td>
<td th:text="${customer.email}">...</td>
</tr>
</th:block>
```

Answer (score 2):

I already found an issue.

Problem was with missing checkbox for Enable annotation processing in Intellij.

Comment: Please, tell us which chekcbox?  how enable it?  I am having same problem with thymeleaf and lombok